# Как отлаживать сервер на python/sanic завёрнутый в docker-compose?

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, sanic

Кофигурация docker-compose:

```
fast_user_api:
    build: .
    command: bash -c "sh ./scripts/scripts_set_app/setup_fast_user_app.sh && python /code/server/server.py"
    env_file:
      - .env
    container_name: fast_user_api
    ports:
      - '8000:8000'
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    depends_on:
      - fast_user_db
    restart: always
```

Конфигурация Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.7.2

RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
ENV PATH=$PATH:/code/api:/code/
ENV PYTHONPATH /code

RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip
RUN pip3 install poetry

COPY . /code/

RUN poetry config virtualenvs.create false --local

RUN poetry install
```

Как видно сервер запускается через скрипт server.py.
Сам код запуска сервера:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = Sanic('name_app')
    app.config.from_object(AppConfig)
    app.run(
        host='localhost',
        port=8000,
        debug=True,
        access_log=True,
    )
```

Создаю в PyCharm`e конфигурацию 'Python' указываю файл для запуска server.py. Сервер запускает, дебаггер коннектиться. Но на точку не встаёт. Как можно это сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Создаю в PyCharm`e конфигурацию 'Python' указываю файл для запуска server.py. Сервер запускает, дебаггер коннектиться. Но на точку не встаёт. Как можно это сделать?

Необходимо добавить строчки в [docker-compose.development.yml](https://github.com/AfsmNGhr/sanic-simple-api/blob/master/docker-compose.development.yml#L13-L16)

```
stdin_open: true
tty: true
environment:
  DEBUG: 'true'
```

И использовать переменную для включения `debug`

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
     app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, debug=DEBUG)
```

Также можно поставить [`sanic-admin`](https://github.com/38elements/sanic-admin) для live-reload (активируется при `debug`).

**Немного советов:**

> FROM python:3.7.2

Тут без проблем можно использовать [alpine python image](https://hub.docker.com/_/python/). Как [пример](https://github.com/AfsmNGhr/sanic-simple-api/blob/master/Dockerfile)

```
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
ENV PATH=$PATH:/code/api:/code/
ENV PYTHONPATH /code
```

**Объединять директивы**

```
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1 \
    PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1 \
    PATH=$PATH:/code/api:/code/ \
    PYTHONPATH /code
```

> RUN mkdir /code

Эта действие не нужно, так как `COPY` создаст нужную директорию.

```
RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip
RUN pip3 install poetry
```

Объединение директив.

**И самое проблемное место.**

```
COPY . /code/
```

При любом изменении кода, будем пересобирать в том числе и python пакеты, даже, если их не меняли.

[Пример](https://github.com/AfsmNGhr/sanic-simple-api/blob/master/Dockerfile#L3-L12) как избежать

```
COPY requirements.txt /

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r /requirements.txt

COPY . /code/
```